# Blender rigid body with curved concave shapes?

Tags: rigidbody

I am trying to create "curved train rails" for game Space Engineers using Blender (havoc) and meet on issue when using Rigib body, the final stages seems not allowing any "concave" shape using Convex hull (obvious so) but not working with "Mesh" insted "convex hull"

So i am looking for any idea or setting in order to do it

Also model builder limit rigid body number to 10 so making small mesh is not really usable.

[image: wrong model]

See here the result, as the wheel will use the TOP and inside corner of the rail (inside each one) i need to keep it as you could see for the straight ones on Left of picture. The curved part is totally filled also from top to bottom (triangular too) when the model builder see it as concave.

[image]

Thanks for help / ideas
should get something like this (but could not really use theses angles as it's needed to have the space between each bogie on each angle at least and will mostly brake on any angle)

Comment: On question formatting: It looks like you moved the image source link when you meant to move the line that displays it. I’ve edited the question with that in mind. Is this correct? Also, I seemed to be encountering ghost characters of some sort while editing. Are you using an unusual browser or keyboard?

Comment: Hello TheLabCat I am using Firefox and nothing unusual, i have French one so maybe with custom chars. I was re editing instead adding picture maybe. About pictures all seems good now thanks